# How to solve for $X$ given $A = X + Y$ and $B = 1 + YX$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

So I have the following system of equations:

$A = X + Y$

$B = 1 + YX$

And I'm asked to solve for $X$ and $Y$.
My question is how do I do so? I was taught that I should first try to isolate $X$ and get it in terms of $A$ and $B$. So my attempt was the following:

$A = X + Y$

$B = 1 + YX$

into

$-A = -X-Y$

$B = 1 + YX$

into

$-AX = -x^2-YX$

$B = 1 + YX$

so adding $-AX + B$ together I get

$B-Ax=-x^2+1$

which does not isolate $X$ in terms of $A$ and $B$ as there's still an $X$ on the LHS

So this is where I get stuck. Can someone please help me figure out the necessary algebra? Is my way of going at this completely wrong? I have the same issue isolating $Y$. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: do you know the quadratic formula?

Comment: How would I use the quadratic formula to solve for x in terms of B and A?

Comment: @YoGoodSlope You take the last equation you got $B−Ax=−x^2+1$ and rewrite it as $x^2 - A x + B - 1 = 0$. That's a quadratic in $x$, which you need to solve for $x$.

Comment: Using [Simon's favourite factoring trick](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Simon%27s_Favorite_Factoring_Trick), $A + B = (X+1)(Y+1), -A + B = (X-1)(Y-1)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$X = A - Y$ and $Y = \frac{B - 1}{X}$ ($X\neq 0$), then $X^2 - AX - B + 1 = 0$. Solving quadratic equation, you get $X = \frac{A \pm \sqrt{A^2 + 4(B - 1)}}{2}$

Answer (score 1):

If you familiar  [Vieta's fomulas](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas)

$$\begin{cases}X+Y= A\\ XY=B-1\end{cases}$$

Then, Vieta gives us

$$t^2-At+(B-1)=0$$

where  $t_1=X,~t_2=Y.$

Answer (score 0):

From the first equation, you get that $Y=A-X$. Now, from the second equation you get that$$B=1+(A-X)X=1-AX+X^2.$$Now, use the quadratic formula.

Answer (score 0):

If we assume that $x=0$ is not a solution, we can write $$x+y-a=0\iff x^2-ax+xy=x^2-ax+b-1=0.$$

Then

$$\left(x-\frac a2\right)^2=1-b+\frac{a^2}2$$

from which you can draw $x$ ($2$ solutions).